# Updating picklist value based on the value of another picklist

Tags: trigger, picklist

I am finally getting close with my trigger.  I at at the point where I need to take the picklist value from one field and update the same value into a picklist with the same value on an unrelated object.  So, Task.Call_Dispositon__c needs to carry over and update CampaignMember.Call_Disposition__c so that they have the same value.  Both are picklists.  Suggestions on how to do this?  I am not certain if when working with the picklists if they return the picklist value id or the text of the picklist field.

```
trigger CallDispositionOnCampaignMember on Task (before insert) {

    list<CampaignMember> myCampaignMembers = new list<CampaignMember>();
    myCampaignMembers = [Select ID, Call_Disposition__c From CampaignMember];

    list<Task> myTasks = new list<Task>();
    myTasks = [Select ID, Campaign_Member_ID__c, Call_Disposition__c From Task Where Campaign_Member_ID__c != null];

    map<string,Task> memIDtoTaskMap = new map <string,Task>();
    for (Task t: myTasks){
        memIDtoTaskMap.put(t.Campaign_Member_ID__c, t );
    }

    for (CampaignMember a: myCampaignMembers){
        if (memIDtoTaskMap.containsKey(a.id)){
            list<Task> newTask = new list <task> (myTasks);
            newTask = [Select ID, Campaign_Member_ID__c, Call_Disposition__c from Task Where Campaign_Member_ID__c = : a.id];

            for (task c: newTask){
                if (c.Campaign_Member_ID__c == a.id){     
                   a.Call_Disposition__c = c.Call_Disposition__c;
                }
                update myCampaignMembers;
            }
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between CampaignMember record and Task record? From what I understand,  the Task record has a lookup to CampaignMember record. And all you want to do in the trigger is, before inserting a Task record, set the Call_Disposition__c field of the related CampaignMember record to be the same as the Call_Disposition__c field of the triggering Task record. Am I correct?

Comment: I created a custom button on the Campaign Member page layout to create a task related to the contact or lead.  Yes, you are correct that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do to achieve this,

```
trigger CallDispositionOnCampaignMember on Task (before insert) {

    //get the ids of the related CampaignMember records of the triggering tasks
    List<Id> campaignMemberIds = new List<Id>();
    for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if(t.Campaign_Member_ID__c != null) {
            campaignMemberIds.add(t.Campaign_Member_ID__c);
        }
    }

    //query out the related CampaignMember records
    Map<Id, CampaignMember> myCampaignMembers = new Map<Id, CampaignMember> ([Select ID, Call_Disposition__c FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id IN :campaignMemberIds]);

    for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if(t.Campaign_Member_ID__c != null && myCampaignMembers.containsKey(t.Campaign_Member_ID__c)){
            myCampaignMembers.get(t.Campaign_Member_ID__c).Call_Disposition__c = t.Call_Disposition__c;
        }
    }
    update myCampaignMembers.values();

}
```

Comment: So I tried with the code here, and got  Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to String at line 16 column 60 
 which is line:   myCampaignMembers.get(t.Campaign_Member_ID__c).Call_Disposition__c = task.Call_Disposition__c;

Comment: I made a mistake in my original code, had task.Call_Disposition__c, instead of t.Call_Disposition__c. check the new code

Comment: You are a Salesforce GURU!  Thank you so much!!!  I was making this tremendously harder than I needed to.  You totally rock!  It works perfectly!!!

Comment: Glad to help. please mark as the answer